# geopandas point in polygon distance to nearest edge

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

So I have a geopandas dataframe of ~10,000 rows like this. Each point is within the polygon (I've made sure of it).

```
point                         name      field_id    geometry
POINT(-0.1618445 51.5103873)  polygon1  1           POLYGON ((-0.1642799 51.5113756, -0.1639581 51.5089851, -0.1593661 51.5096729, -0.1606536 51.5115358, -0.1642799 51.5113756))
```

I want to add a new column called `distance_to_nearest_edge`. Which is the distance from the `point` to the nearest boundary of the polygon.

There is a shapely function that calculates what I want:

```
from shapely import wkt
poly = wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-0.1642799 51.5113756, -0.1639581 51.5089851, -0.1593661 51.5096729, -0.1606536 51.5115358, -0.1642799 51.5113756))')
pt = wkt.loads('POINT(-0.1618445 51.5103873)')
dist = poly.boundary.distance(pt)
---
dist = 0.0010736436340879488
```

But I'm struggling to apply this to 10k rows.

I've tried creating a function, but I keep getting errors `("'Polygon' object has no attribute 'encode'", 'occurred at index 0')`

Eg:

```
def fxy(x, y):
    poly = wkt.loads(x)
    pt = wkt.loads(y)
    return poly.exterior.distance(pt)
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: does your function work on simple x & y?

Comment: You don't need to use `wkt.loads` because you already have shapely geomerties in your DataFrame: `gdf.apply(lambda row: row['geometry'].boundary.distance(row['point']), axis=1)`

Comment: @adhg Yes the function works on `x` and `y`. Eg. 
def fxy(x, y):
    poly = x
    pt = y
    return poly.exterior.distance(pt)
@PaulH - I tried that, but I get the following error:
`
AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'boundary'", 'occurred at index 6')
`
It's strange, because the function works when I supply the inputs, but not a dataframe...

Comment: @Kvothe would you please tell me which coordinates reference system did you for distance calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I think your data has missing values.
you can try this:

```py
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda row : row['point'].distance(row['geometry'].boundary) if pd.notnull(row['point']) & pd.notnull(row['geometry']) else np.nan, axis=1)
```